# MYSQL Queries to find immediate next DateTime

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I was writing a mini scheduler that perform certain task. 
For calculating trigger time, I am using MYSQL. I am stucked at writing one of the query.

Find *immediate DateTime* which is greater than the  given prevtime,

AND

the Day of the required *immediate datetime* should be ANY of given days

AND

time(HH:MM:SS) portion of required *immediate datetime* should be equal to given time.

Examples:

(a)

If given days are ('MON', 'WEDNES', 'SAT'),

given time is 10:15:00,

given prevtime is 2014-11-12 23:17:00

Then MYSQL should return
*2014-11-15 10:15:00*

(b)

Given Days: ('SUN','SAT','TUES')

Given Time: 09:10:00

Given prevtime is 2014-11-30 07:05:12

MYSQL should return *2014-11-30 09:10:00*

(c)

Given Days: ('MON','THURS','SAT')

Given Time: 11:00:00

Given prevtime is 2014-12-29 11:55:12

MYSQL should return *2015-01-01 11:00:00*

(d)
Days: (SUN, THURS, SAT)'

Given prevtime is  2014-02-27 18:15:00

Given Time 15:15:00

MYSQL Query result: *2014-03-01 15:15:00*

(e)

DAYS: (TUES, WED, FRI)

Prev Date: 2014-12-23 09:30:00

Time : 08:00:00

Expected Result:

*2014-12-24 08:00:00*

(f)

DAYS: SUN, TUES, THURS

Prev Date: 2014-07-31 10:10:00

Time: 06:07:08

Expected Res:
*2014-08-03 06:07:08*

Comment: which programming language are you using? I think this is not a mysql-task.

Comment: I am trying to use MYSQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Using numeric weekday numbers, 0=Monday, 6=Sunday:

```
set @day1=0;
set @day2=2;
set @day3=5;
set @time=time('10:15:00');
set @prevtime=timestamp('2014-11-12 23:17:00');

select if(weekday(@nexttime:=date_add(concat(date(@prevtime),' ',@time),interval if(@time>time(@prevtime),0,1) day)) in (@day1,@day2,@day3),@nexttime,if(weekday(@nexttime:=date_add(@nexttime,interval 1 day)) in (@day1,@day2,@day3),@nexttime,if(weekday(@nexttime:=date_add(@nexttime,interval 1 day)) in (@day1,@day2,@day3),@nexttime,if(weekday(@nexttime:=date_add(@nexttime,interval 1 day)) in (@day1,@day2,@day3),@nexttime,if(weekday(@nexttime:=date_add(@nexttime,interval 1 day)) in (@day1,@day2,@day3),@nexttime,if(weekday(@nexttime:=date_add(@nexttime,interval 1 day)) in (@day1,@day2,@day3),@nexttime,date_add(@nexttime,interval 1 day))))))) as nexttime;
```

If you have only one weekday, you can set all three variables to the same number.

Comment: Its returning wrong value for following cases: `SET @day1='2';

SET @time=TIME('05:15:00');
SET @prevtime=TIMESTAMP('2014-11-20 06:57:27 ');

SELECT IF(WEEKDAY(@nexttime:=DATE_ADD(CONCAT(DATE(@prevtime),' ',@time),INTERVAL IF(@time>TIME(@prevtime),0,1) DAY)) IN (@day1),@nexttime,IF(WEEKDAY(@nexttime:=DATE_ADD(@nexttime,INTERVAL 1 DAY)) IN (@day1),@nexttime,IF(WEEKDAY(@nexttime:=DATE_ADD(@nexttime,INTERVAL 1 DAY)) IN (@day1),@nexttime,IF(WEEKDAY(@nexttime:=DATE_ADD(@nexttime,INTERVAL 1 DAY)) IN (@day1),@nexttime,DATE_ADD(@nexttime,INTERVAL 1 DAY))))) AS nexttime;`

Comment: Case 2:
`SET @day1='3';

SET @time=TIME('05:15:00');
SET @prevtime=TIMESTAMP('2014-11-20 06:57:27');

SELECT IF(WEEKDAY(@nexttime:=DATE_ADD(CONCAT(DATE(@prevtime),' ',@time),INTERVAL IF(@time>TIME(@prevtime),0,1) DAY)) IN (@day1),@nexttime,IF(WEEKDAY(@nexttime:=DATE_ADD(@nexttime,INTERVAL 1 DAY)) IN (@day1),@nexttime,IF(WEEKDAY(@nexttime:=DATE_ADD(@nexttime,INTERVAL 1 DAY)) IN (@day1),@nexttime,IF(WEEKDAY(@nexttime:=DATE_ADD(@nexttime,INTERVAL 1 DAY)) IN (@day1),@nexttime,DATE_ADD(@nexttime,INTERVAL 1 DAY))))) AS nexttime;`

Comment: For Case 1 and 2: `2014-11-26 05:15:00`
& `2014-11-27 05:15:00` respectively are correct val.

Comment: I was assuming three different days; it needs a slight change to work with only one.  Will edit.

Comment: Ok. Tkanks for your swift response. If 1 day is selected, then I can set@day1=@day2=@day3=selected_numericVal, and it returned expected val. Now if 2 days are selected, then it returns incorrect val. Query Only works well if No of days selected are >=3.

Comment: Looks like you already edited and fixed the query. It returns correct val. My Bad!!.Please ignore the last comment. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to formulate the where clause using the DAYNAME(), HOUR(), MINUTE() and SECOND() functions:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

If performance is inadequate and you start wishing you could index on DAYNAME(columname) for example, you can consider denormalizing your data and storing the DAYNAME value separately.
It might be simpler to switch to Postgres at that point though:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html